# AFNetworking valueForKeyPath Wildcard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Im trying to get the tvrage_name from the following JSON file.

```
{
    data: {
           Band of Brothers: {
                              air_by_date: 0,
                              cache: {
                                      banner: 1,
                                      poster: 1
                                      },
                              language: "en",
                              network: "HBO",
                              next_ep_airdate: "",
                              paused: 0,
                              quality: "Any",
                              status: "Ended",
                              tvdbid: 74205,
                              tvrage_id: 2708,
                              tvrage_name: "Band of Brothers"
                              },
           Breaking Bad: {
                              air_by_date: 0,
                              cache: {
                              banner: 1,
                              poster: 1
                              },
                              language: "en",
                              network: "AMC",
                              next_ep_airdate: "2013-07-14",
                              paused: 0,
                              quality: "HD",
                              status: "Continuing",
                              tvdbid: 81189,
                              tvrage_id: 18164,
                              tvrage_name: "Breaking Bad"
                              },
          },
          message: "",
          result: "success"
}
```

Is there any way to have a wildcard in the valueForKeyPath?
So the valueForKeyPath would be: data.*.tvrage_name (the * would be the wildcard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You will have to loop over the key/values like this*:

```
...
NSDictionary *data = [JSON valueForKey:@"data"];
for (NSString *movie in data) {
    NSLog(@"tvrage_name: %@", [[data valueForKey:movie] valueForKey:@"tvrage_name"]);
}
...
```

*I like to be on the safe side so I always have extra checks. e.g. `[JSON isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]`, etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good. Remember to set the question as answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a copy of the dictionary with just the tv show entries (not 'message' and 'result'), then you can do `[[shows allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"tvrage_name"]`

This should work since allValues gives you an array of dictionaries and so valueForKeyPath will in turn give you an array of values under the given key.

(However it's probably a bad idea to do this without additional checks or hardening when getting JSON over a network, in case the JSON is not structured as you expected)